# Listen to MIDI events from AKSequencer

Tags: swift, audiokit, aksequencer

AudioKit 4.9. I would like to receive MIDI events from the new `AKSequencer`, handle them and send the handled data to an external gear connected to a midi port of an audio interface like I can do with `AKMIDICallbackInstrument` set to an output of `AKAppleSequencer`. Investigating the source code I've figured out that there are two ways to receive MIDI from `AKSequencerEngineDSPKernel` (an internal sequencer in `AKSequencer`) : in `AudioUnit` and via `MIDIEndpoint`. I couldn't find any `AudioUnit` alternative for `AKMIDICallbackInstrument`, thus I wonder if there is any way to pass a value to `midiEndpoint` of `AKSequencerEngineDSPKernel` to correspond the `AKMIDICallbackInstrumen.midiIn`? It's possible that I missed something, please explain a better way to solve this problem.